# How to stop the program flow till AsyncTask finish which presents in activity and that activity gets called from non activity class

Tags: android, class, android-intent

I have one non activity java class its name is `AsynClassValue`, it has following code and method

```
public class AsynClassValue
{ 
  public static int a;

  public void getValue()
  {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getContext(),AsyncActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            MyApplication.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            System.out.println("value of variable a"+a);
  }
}
```

I am starting the new Activity from this class in `getValue()` method.

I have used MyApplication class it has the application context.

In `AsyncActivity` is an `Activity` and it has `AsyncTask` in it and on its `onPostExecute()` method I am assigning the value to the static variable "a" of `AsynClassValue` and finally I am printing the value of the variable "a" in `AsynClassValue` class.

The problem is that I am getting the value of variable "a" is `null` though the print statement is next after starting of the intent.

So how to stop the control flow of program till All task finish by activity class started using intent and after that next print statement.

Comment: *How to stop the program flow till AsyncTask finish* by not using AsyncTask at all

Answer (score 0):

You don't - Instead move the stuff to do later (the println in your case) into a new method.  When the Activity/AsyncTask is done call this new method (depending on the structure of your project this may involve other stuff).

So you end up with something like:

```
public class AsynClassValue
{ 
  public static int a;

  public void getValue()
  {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getContext(),AsyncActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            MyApplication.getContext().startActivity(intent);
  }

  public void doLater()
  {
            System.out.println("value of variable a"+a);
  }
}
```

After you finish giving 'a' the proper value in onPostExecute(), then arrange to call doLater().  In this example you can simplify things by making doLater() static, but that won't work in more complicated situations.

Comment: actually i want to return that variable "a" from getValue() method in another class but the return statement executes first before intent and i gets the null value for variable "a".

Comment: Basically you can't pause getValue() without causing your app to freeze until the background task finishes.  You will have to use where you intend to use 'a' and create an equivalent of doLater() there, possibly splitting other methods as well.

Comment: I want to hold the control flow of getValue() till variable "a" gets assign the value in onPostExecute, can we do this using threading, i tried Thread.sleep(1000) but it also sleep intent and background task as well, how can we stop the program flow using thread without stopping the background task.

Comment: I would ask if you need the getValue() thread to wait, then what is the reason for the AsyncTask?  So I would say either do it directly without an AsyncTask, or use the AsyncTask and a doLater() callback method.